# Is browser cache and our system cache (that reside b/w CPU and main memory) are different or same only?

Tags: browser-cache

When we browse in the browser for the same website that we have browsed previously then the observe loads it immediately from the cache memory. Similarly when we access some files from our local system's drive then we see that our system shows the recent files(see the image attached) so I am thinking that these files are available in our system cache so it is showing. Now clear me that actually the browser cache and the system cache are different caches or only one cache reside in our whole system?

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you asking if all caches in a system are the same cache?  A cache is a thing, your system will have numerous caches, sometimes one part of your system will have multiple layers of caches as well.

Answer (score 0):

The browser has its own logical "cache". Every file is stored to the disk and read from there.

The system handles all "file caches" and therefore some data may (still) be in memory when the browser tries to access the file.

These are some different type of "caching" that you're trying to understand.